# Are docx and/or ms-word considerable for burnination?

Tags: discussion

I think this is my first burnination idea, so let's discuss about it first. Hopefully I followed all the rules and could give reasonable answers to the burnination questions. The affected tags have quite a high use, so maybe it's not appropriate to burn them.

### Affected tags

[docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx) (~1000 questions) says

> `.docx` is the file extension for files created using the default format of Microsoft Word 2007 or higher.

[ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) (~7800 questions) says

> Microsoft Word is a commercial word processor designed by Microsoft.

In both cases, it does not become clear what the tag is really about. It is open which technology is being used to process the document.

Both hardly give any usage advice, even in their long version. [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) has a bit of guidance:

> [...] it is expected that questions using this tag relate to Word programming [...]

but whole Stack Overflow is about programming, so you could remove the word "programming" from that sentence. And what's left? The question is about Word...

### Our rules

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

`docx` describes the content of the file, not the content of the question. It is ambiguous, because docx could also refer to [DocX on codeplex](https://docx.codeplex.com), for which IMHO the tag would fit *much* better.

`ms-word` first sounds like a tag for Super User, not specifically related to programming. At least it's hardly ambiguous.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Both do not describe a concept, right?

[docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx) is a file format, the concept behind is probably [openxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml).

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

At least it's more restricted than [ms-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office)...

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

[ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) is ok for me.

As I said, [docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx) to me is [DocX on codeplex](https://docx.codeplex.com), so the answer is "No".

### Better alternatives

That's where

[openxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml) (~1800 questions) (or also [openxml-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openxml-sdk))

> Questions regarding reading and writing of Microsoft Office Open XML files either through direct manipulation of the XML files contained in a zip package or through the Microsoft Office Open XML SDK.

or [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba) (~1600 questions)

> Word-VBA is (Visual Basic for Applications for MS-WORD) is the dominant programming language for Microsoft Office Word.

IMHO fit much better.

### Question

From the SO process perspective, is it correct to request burnination? Or is there a chance to improve the tag wiki (especially the short version) to give the needed usage guidance?

Comment: Note, you did a good job with your request. I'm just downvoting to indicate disagreement.

Comment: There may be a mundane reason for the explicit reference to programming in [tag:ms-word]: without it, people would ask their MS Word support questions in here. (Even more than [already is happening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364703/enter-key-symbol-wingdings3-8-in-ms-word-2010-not-spaced-properly).) Not unique to Word; other "programmable" software [has the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153005/indesign-dot-moves-to-beginning-of-line).

Comment: @Jongware They also ask their MS Word support questions in ELU! It’s a plague.

Comment: *docx describes the content of the file, not the content of the question.* incorrect.  It is a file *format*.  A subset of [tag:XML], in fact.  If you think docx should be banned, so must xml.

Answer (score 3):

[docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docx) *could* perhaps use some disambiguation if, as you say, there is another technology that could be tagged the same. Perhaps [ms-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-docx)?

That said, I don't feel it is a good candidate for burnination as it helps classify the question (it's clearly asking for help programming against a .docx file). People can be experts in doing so, and *could* be following the tag.

[ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word) is *certainly* useful. You can write programs for word, and with more than just VBA. For example, [office-interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-interop) and [office-addins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-addins) both of these would be clarified in a question by having [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word). Its certainly on-topic (though its wiki could be improved). Again, experts for writing programs relating to Word almost certainly exist, and could be following the tag.

If it was removed, the next best tag is [ms-office](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-office) which isn't nearly as specific.

So no, I wouldn't support burninating either of these tags. That said, you did follow the correct protocol by asking here!

Comment: (not downvoting) Why do we have such generic tags as `office-addins`? Wouldn't it be better to have `word-addin`? The short tag wiki of `office-interop` sounds wrong (at the time of writing: "Office Interop is the layer using the COM Interop that allows .NET or C# to communicate with standard COM objects and libraries."). There is at least the word "Office" missing. There are `outlook-addin` and `excel-addins` which are more specific. However, there's no `word-addin`. That's not very consistent...

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'd personally think that we would have [tag:office-addins] combined with each general program tag, but I *could* support going the other way with enough persuasion :). Keeping it the same allows for behavior we see today such as tagging [tag:c#], [tag:wpf], [tag:xaml] to indicate the specific area you are asking about while getting views from more general tag followers and letting readers have some context (if the question was about XAML in the context of C#/WPF)

Comment: On that note, I *would* like to see these get consistent! I would be interested to hear the downvoter's opinion as well :).

Comment: Ok. Maybe I slowly get your point :-) (it's probably me thinking so slow, not you explaining bad)